# how to get the fully qualified instance id from data which is stored in storage account table in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-group, azure-storage-account

I want to get the fully qualified instance id(Ex-:"`/subscriptions/9xxxxxx5-6xxe-4xxc-8xx4-2xxxxxxxxx5/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-test`")which is stored in storage account table in Azure.

I have enabled guest level monitoring in my virtual machine and exported metrics to a Storage account table. In that table, instance id column (PARTITIONKEY) shows like below.
"`:002Fsubscriptions:002F9xxxxxx5:002D6xxe:002D4xxc:002D8xx4:002D2xxxxxxxxx5:002FresourceGroups:002Ftest:002Fproviders:002FMicrosoft:002ECompute:002FvirtualMachines:002Fvm:002Dtest`"

Comment: Which method do you want to get it? or What's your purpose?

Comment: @NancyXiong My purpose is to get vm memory related metrics (/builtin/memory/usedmemory) of virtual machine and read metric values using api or java sdk. This metric is not available in metrics list api( learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) Therefore I have enabled guest level monitoring to get that metric

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to convert instance id column PARTITIONKEY into like a instance Id.

However, for your purpose to get vm memory related metrics. It's recommended to use Log Analytics. Search Log Analytics workspace resource in the Azure portal then narrow down to your specific VM scope then run the query language.

```
Perf 
| where ObjectName == "Memory"
```

[image]

Or, you can execute an Analytics query using [Query - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get)

For more information, you could read these docs.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-portal
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll check.